# Creating a button in the Playground app on iPad

Tags: ios, swift-playground

I am working with the new beta version of the Playground app in iOS 10.
I want to get some UIKit elements working in a playground.
Swift 3 is just different enough from Swift 2, I am having some problems.

I got a label and text box working, but I cannot get a button working.
I have the button showing up but cannot get text in it or an action working on touch-up.
Here is my code I have.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

//
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.909803926944733, green: 0.47843137383461, blue: 0.643137276172638, alpha: 1.0)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
lbl.text = "Hello, World!"
view.addSubview(lbl)

let txt = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 50))
//txt.placeholder = "Enter text here"
//txt.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
view.addSubview(txt)

func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)
{
    //sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.725490212440491, green: 0.47843137383461, blue: 0.0980392172932625, alpha: 1.0)
}

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644046783, green: 0.886274516582489, blue: 0.592156887054443, alpha: 1.0)
button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControlState.focused)
button.setTitle("button", for: UIControlState.focused)
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
button.addTarget(button, action: "buttonPressed", for:  UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 5):

I've been trying the same and the following code works for me:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class Receiver {
    @objc func buttonClicked() {
        print("click")
    }
}

let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
let receiver = Receiver()
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 50))
button.setTitle("TestButton", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.474509805440903, green: 0.839215695858002, blue: 0.976470589637756, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(receiver, action: #selector(Receiver.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
view.addSubview(button)
```

I think the important difference is that you add the button as target of the `.touchUpInside` event. Unfortunately, the button does not implement your `buttonPressed` method (it's just defined in the Playground, not as part of the UIButton class). As there is no `self` in a general playground (to refer to the function you wrote), I wrapped it into a new class and used an instance of this class to be the receiver of the `.touchUpInside` event.

Comment: I have created another view I wish to interact with within my buttonClicked function in the Receiver class. How do you do this without passing parameters? In a Playground.

Comment: I found a temp fix but don't know if it's the proper way to do it. I created a function outside of the class and have the buttonClicked function call it.

Comment: @MaxNelson As long as you define the other view/object before the Receiver class und function, you should be able to access it directly as well